# Proof of Sard's theorem.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, differential-topology

In proof of Sard's theorem in Guillemin as well as in Milnor we consider $C$ such that if $x \in C$ then $\text{rank} \ df_x < p$  of function $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb R^p$, $U \subset R^n$ and $C_i$ such that all the partial derivatives of order $\leq i$ are $0$. In the proof of the theorem the following appears

> For each $x \in C-C_1, \exists  V \ \text{open}, x\in V $ such that $f(V \cap C)   $ has measure $0$.

How to prove this?

Comment: This claim is not presented without proof...the proof is immediately afterwards.

Comment: Guillemin and Pollack relegate the proof of Sard's theorem to the appendix and if I recall correctly Milnor has the proof of Sard's theorem in a chapter after he utilizes it.